# grid_random function errors out: 'object' should be a 'quant_param' object

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, hyperparameters, tidymodels

I am going through a blog post on tidymodels (random forest regression) and for some reason, I keep getting **Error: `object` should be a 'quant_param' object** when I run the code chunk below

```
grid_tidym <- grid_random(
  mtry %>% range_set(c( 1,  14)),
  trees %>% range_set(c( 500, 1000)), 
  min_n %>% range_set(c(2,  10)),
  size = 30
)
```

How do I get out of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/grid-random-function-errors-out-object-should-be-a-quant-param-object/49647/3); parameter objects are generated by functions (e.g. `mtry()`).